# Stateless widget and Widget function difference

Tags: function, flutter, widget

I have read the difference between Stateless widgets and functions that return a Widget and I know that the framework can recognize classes but not functions. In the below code, I have a floating button, in which I call the setState() and in both cases the appbar rebuilds (stateless widget and function), so in this context are these two any different?

```
      appBar: 
       AppBarv1(title: widget.title,)
      // customAppBar(title: widget.title)
       ,
       floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(backgroundColor: Colors.blue,onPressed: (){
         setState(() {
                    
                  });
       },),
      body: 
      Center(
      ),
      
    );

PreferredSizeWidget customAppBar({String title}) {
  print('appbar is built');
  return AppBar(
    title: Text(title),
    actions: [],
  );
}

class AppBarv1 extends PreferredSize {

  const AppBarv1({this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('appbar is built');
    return AppBar(
    title: Text(title),
    actions: [],
  );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

They are no different, other than that the function executes before the Widget is returned. The Widget-Tree you end up with, is identical.